# How to capture error logs from browser console while running test for webdriver io v7 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, wdio

So browser.getLogs() is deprecated which was in package JsonWireProtocol which is replaced by WebDriver protocol. I want to capture browser logs (Error and warnings) when the test shows the reports, I cant find something similar in the docs, but I found a command called addConsoleLogs(https://webdriver.io/docs/spec-reporter/#addconsolelogs),if someone has a running example to show would be great. Thank you
(using webdriver io v7)
I have already tried browser.getLogs() but no luck so looking forward to other approaches with an example.

Answer (score 0):

On your `wdio.conf.js` add the following configuration:

```
reporters: [
  [
    'spec',
      {
        addConsoleLogs: true,
      },
  ], 
]
```

---

Then on your test you can add a `console.log` add see logs on terminal.

Comment: How can one save the logs in folder inside the project folder?